# How to sum values from a dictionary that is embedded in another dictionary in Python?

Tags: python

```
part_1 = {'Ingredient':'Water', 'Amount wt':40 }
part_2 = {'Ingredient':'Dye', 'Amount wt': 50 }
part_3 = {'Ingredient':'Salt', 'Amount wt':10 }

total_mix = {'index 1': part_1,
             'index 2': part_2,
             'index 3': part_3}

print(total_mix)
```

I have a dictionary that contains another dictionary like the example above. How can I easily sum up the wt of the total mix?

I have tried making a list like:

```
mix_list = (total_mix['index 1']['Amount wt'], total_mix['index 2']['Amount wt'], total_mix['index 3']['Amount wt'])
```

And then using sum() to add them all up and it does work, but I want to know if there is an easier/shorter way to do this. Especially since it feels like it will be very time consuming if there was more items in the dictionaries. Also the dictionary has to be able to call the info with the index numbers, which is why I put it into another dictionary to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is in a one-liner:

```
print(sum(part["Amount wt"] for part in total_mix.values()))
```

This uses `total_mix.values()` to get the individual part dictionaries, and uses a [generator expression](https://www.pythontutorial.net/advanced-python/python-generator-expressions/) to get the "Amount wt" value in each dictionary. As [sum()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) accepts an iterable, and generator expressions are iterables, we can pass the generator expression to it directly and it will sum up the "Amount wt" values for us.

Comment: *print(sum(part.get("Amount wt",0) for part in total_mix.values()))* is arguably better in that it won't fail if the 'Amount wt' key is absent

Comment: @Pingu That depends: do you want to fail fast if your data is invalid, or do you want your code to be more tolerant of invalid data? If the former, use `part["Amount wt"]`, and if the latter, use `part.get("Amount wt", 0)`. For example, if you use `part["Amount wt"]`, then you can detect invalid data like `{'Ingredient':'Flour', 'Amount qt':40 }`, where "Amount wt" is misspelled.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop to iterate over the items in `total_mix` and add the values of the `Amount wt` key for each inner dictionary.

```
total_wt = 0
for part in total_mix.values():
    total_wt += part['Amount wt']

print("Total weight:", total_wt)
```

---

Another solution

```
total_wt = sum(part['Amount wt'] for part in total_mix.values())
print("Total weight:", total_wt)
```

---

Output

```
Total weight: 100
```

Comment: Why not use `sum()` with a generator expression?

Comment: Or a list comprehension: `print(sum(inner_dict['Amount wt'] for inner_dict in total_mix.values()))` really the sum thing, just a matter of preference

Comment: @Caridorc There's no list in that comprehension

Comment: @wjandrea yeah generator comprehension

Answer (score 1):

Previous one-line works perfectly, here is simple for-loop, which you could try as well:

It's not fancy, but it serves the purpose. *(for beginner too)*

```py
total = 0

for _, v in total_mix.items():
    #amt = v.get('Amount wt')
    total += v.get('Amount wt')   # dv.get(...) just syntax sugar 
here 
    # or this way
    #total += dv['Amount wt']      # Edit based on comments

print(total)
# 100
```

Comment: Why `get` instead of `[]`?

Comment: I mean, that suggests 1) that the value doesn't always exist and 2) that you can add `None` (which is misleading).

Comment: OK. Fair point.  Edit it to the notes.

Comment: *total += v.get('Amount wt', 0)* is more robust. If the 'Amount wt' is not available, zero will be added to the total. However, this also means that if the key **should** exist then you won't know that the input dictionary is broken